# Typo3 9 solr-extension indexing errors

Tags: solr, typo3-9.x

When Indexing a Page containing at least one special character I get the following error:

> RuntimeException: Failed to execute Page Indexer Request. See log for details. Request ID: 5eb935f1827a7 in E:\wwwroot_T9LTS\typo3conf\ext\solr\Classes\IndexQueue\PageIndexerRequest.php:222

Though it doesn't effect every special character:
e.g.:
a - works
ä - works
á - works
à - Indexing fails

I think it is an small configuration Error (at the moment using the Base Configuration delivered with the extension), but where could it be?

**solr.log:**

```
{
    "request ID": "5eb935f1827a7",
    "request url": "https:/masked.com/en/masked/masked/masked/masked",
    "request headers": [
        "User-Agent: TYPO3",
        "X-Tx-Solr-Iq: {\"requestId\":\"5eb935f1827a7\",\"item\":42302,\"page\":117,\"actions\":\"indexPage\",\"hash\":\"cf1a90acbe5d74434f6de0a217d8d81e\",\"loggingEnabled\":\"1\",\"accessRootline\":\"c:0\"}"
    ],
    "response headers": {
        "Date": [
            "Mon, 11 May 2020 11:24:33 GMT"
        ],
        "Server": [
            "Apache/2.4.43 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1g"
        ],
        "Strict-Transport-Security": [
            "max-age=31556926; includeSubDomains"
        ],
        "X-Frame-Options": [
            "SAMEORIGIN"
        ],
        "X-Content-Type-Options": [
            "nosniff"
        ],
        "X-XSS-Protection": [
            "1; mode=block"
        ],
        "Content-Length": [
            "0"
        ],
        "Content-Type": [
            "application/json"
        ]
    },
    "raw response body": ""
}
```

Used versions:
 - TYPO3 Version: 9.5.16
 - EXT:solr Version: 10.0.1
 - Used Apache Solr Version: 8.2.0
 - PHP Version: 7.2.27
 - MySQL Version: 5.7.30

Comment: Does the Solr log inside Solr say anything useful?

Comment: no, the solr log in solr says nothing